# C# Process is terminated due to StackOverflowException

Tags: c#

Я очень сильно начинающий, помогите пожалуйста.

В обычный Form1 добавляю progressBar. Называю его progressBar1.

Из соседнего файла и класса пытаюсь передать значение value для progressBar1. Я так понял, что из-за этого возникает рекурсия. Подскажите, как правильно получить доступ к value?

Form1.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Class1 cls=new Class1(100);
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Class1.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
    class Class1
    {
        public Class1(int a)
        {
            Form1 prb = new Form1();
            prb.progressBar1.Value = a;
        }
    }
}
```

Form.Designer.cs

```
namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
    partial class Form1
    {

        private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing && (components != null))
            {
                components.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }

        #region Код, автоматически созданный конструктором форм Windows

        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            this.progressBar1 = new System.Windows.Forms.ProgressBar();
            this.SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // progressBar1
            // 
            this.progressBar1.ForeColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.ControlText;
            this.progressBar1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(115, 120);
            this.progressBar1.Name = "progressBar1";
            this.progressBar1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(493, 66);
            this.progressBar1.TabIndex = 0;
            // 
            // Form1
            // 
            this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(12F, 25F);
            this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
            this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(800, 450);
            this.Controls.Add(this.progressBar1);
            this.Name = "Form1";
            this.Text = "Form1";
            this.Load += new System.EventHandler(this.Form1_Load);
            this.ResumeLayout(false);

        }

        #endregion

        public System.Windows.Forms.ProgressBar progressBar1;
    }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Form1` создает `Class1`,  а `Class1` создает `Form1`.

*Round and round it goes, where it stops nobody knows.*

Передавайте `progressBar1` объекту `Class1` снаружи.

```
    ProgressBar pBar;

    public Class1(int a, ProgressBar pBar)
    {
        this.pBar = pBar;
        this.pBar.Value = a;
    }
```

...

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Class1 cls = new Class1(100, progressBar1);
    }
```